# How to get a specific date selected on Button Click in TableCalendar Widget under table_calendar package Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using TableCalendar under table_calendar package in Flutter..Now I want when I press a button..the selected day will be 7 days before the present date..i.e. As today is 6th Feb,,  it will select 30th of January..

Here is the code

```
TableCalendar(
              initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
              availableCalendarFormats: const {
                CalendarFormat.month: "month",
              },
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                todayColor: Colors.blue,
                selectedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                todayStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                    color: Colors.red),
              ),
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                centerHeaderTitle: true,
                formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.brown,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                ),
                formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                formatButtonShowsNext: false,
              ),
              startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
              /*onDaySelected: (date, events) {  
                  print(date.toUtc());  
                },*/
              builders: CalendarBuilders(
                selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(
                          0xffF86D37), //Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  child: Text(
                    date.day.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffF86D37),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    date.day.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              calendarController: _calendarController,
            ),
```

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: I have added the code details. For convenience....

Comment: Where you are saved new value to local variable?